# Get specific object from Parse (.com) query result by field without going back to DB

Tags: javascript, database, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

So say I do a query on Parse database and get a results object, with each result having a field **place_id**.

How can I then get a specific object by place_id from the results without actually going back to the database (want to minimise network traffic and db querying...)?

This is what my query will look like:

```
var LatestUpdate = Parse.Object.extend("LatestUpdate");
var query = new Parse.Query(LatestUpdate);
query.containedIn("place_id", arrayOfplaceIds);
query.find().then(
  function(results){
    // and then i want to do something like:
    return results.findByField("place_id", 1234) // get a specific object from the result without going back to the database?
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop through your results and find the object that matches your criteria. You can do this easily using `underscore.js` which is supported on the cloud:

```
var match = _.find(results, function(object){ return object.get("place_id") == 1234; });
```

Just make sure your have `var _ = require('underscore');` on top of your js file.

Comment: Thanks - i did end up writing my own function without underscore